# Can't get sockets working - what silly thing am I missing?

Tags: php, javascript, websocket

I am trying to get into the brave new world of web sockets, but I can't get anything working.

I have downloaded and tried several PHP socket servers, but no joy. They seem very scarce on step-by-step info on what to do to actually get the thing working on your own server.

I am passing the path to the server script as the first argument to new WebSocket() - e.g. 'ws://localhost:33/sockets/server.php'. Is that right?

Should I be passing anything as the second param? I've read up, but I'm not quite sure.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Path that you are passing to WebSockets have nothing to do with actual Path within filesystem.
When WebSocket is connecting to server, it just uses actual address "localhost" in your case, and port "33". Then in HTTP request on handshaking it will take the "path" details which is "/sockets/server.php" in your case, and will put them in handshake, so first line of handshake will look like that:

```
GET /sockets/server.php HTTP/1.1
```

So it will be used by you application to decide what to do with it. If you want to use it and make it look like related to actual files or use it your own way.

[Here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#page-14) is some info from RFC 6455 on WebSockets URIs.

As well do not use port 33, as it is might be taken by dsp service. Check ports map [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers).
If you Bind your server side WebSocket to port 33, then it should proceed with connection.

After connection of TCP layer is established, it should proceed through HTTP Requests that is Handshaking.

After that is done, and was success. JavaScript on client side will throw onopen callback. If something went wrong it will throw onerror and onclose events.

After connection is successfully established and WebSocket did proceed through handshaking messaging can be made. Client will receive raw string as message, or binary (if server sends binary data, message with specific opcode). But server will receive data with framing and some header. Browsers do apply deframing automatically so on Client side you dont need to worry about that. But on Server side you have to do it or yourself, or use some existing libraries to handle that for you.

Here is official document of WebSockets protocol: [RFC 6455](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455). It has all information you need to know all aspects of WebSockets protocol.

In meantime, you might be interested for looking into ready solutions. And go through their examples.

Comment: Thanks, Maksims. It's your first sentence that I don't quite get. I've seen things like WebSocket('localhost/path/to/file.php'), so that seems to be pointing to a file. I have tried ready examples but they of course require you to change the settings re: host, path, port etc, and it's that I don't understand and they don't seem to explain.

Comment: I've added some info describing what you path is in top of the answer. Hope it will make it clear.

Comment: Thanks again, Maksims. I'm afraid I'm still a little lost. 1) Most of the blogs/tutorials on this talk about using the PHP console - is that necessary? 2) Step 2 of [this pretty vague tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/start-using-html5-websockets-today/) says "Change the server according to your setup", without saying what that actually means, e.g. what port should I specify? 3) I tried installing the source files of that tutorial and I couldn't figure out what to change, and to what, to get anything to work. Sorry...